RPC attack when Server is on VPN
I have a problem that I cannot understand.
This is my first question on this site, so in addition to downvote please tell me where I can improve the question.
On Windows Server 2022 I  see several RDP attack each day, so I installed OpenVPN server.
OpenVPN Installation

I installed and configured OpenVPN Server, for tunneling. Created private 10.8.0/24 network.
I deactivated Firewall rules for opening RDP Port.
I changed Firewall properties for not protecting "OpenVPN Tap-WindowsX". Without this step, the firewall blocks also traffic in private 10.8.0/24 network and no one could connect with RDP.

The Windows Network and Sharing Centre appear as following:

Firewall Configuration
The firewall is configured to block by default incoming connection in all the three profiles.
I have excluded the OpenVPN Tap-Windows6 network from the firewall in all profiles.
I have some rules for allowing some port/programs, but I have disabled the RDP port rules. In fact I cannot connect with RDP with server public IP address:RDP port.
The problem
After installing VPN:

I cannot access the server with RDP without VPN (I try to connect to public server IP address).
I can access the server with RDP if I have OpenVPN Client already connected (I can connect to private server IP address).

Now, I still have RDP intrusion attempts, as seen in RDPGuard software. I have performed these checks:

no one connected with VPN during the time of intrusion attempts, as seen in OpenVPN Server logs.
attackers IP are not in 10.8.0/24 network.

I cannot understand how attackers by-passed the firewall. It seems they have a connection to a public IP address to a 10.8.0/24 network, but without an OpenVPN client connected how could this be done?
Firewall was configured to log only dropped packets, so I cannot see anything about RDP intrusion attempts.
Surely I have done something wrong, but I cannot figure what.
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thank You
--- Update 1 ---
After some investigation, with firewall configured for logging also permitted packets, I'm quite sure that the problem was port 135.
After closing port 135 in the firewall public profile, I did not see any other intrusion attempt in RDPGuard.
I still cannot understand how an attacker can use port 135 to reach my RDP server, but I do not have a good knowledge of Windows RPC.
In particular for me is inexplicable that, in firewall logs, I cannot see the RDP port in the intrusion attempts.
--- Update 2 ---
I can share the portion of firewall log for intrusion attempt. RDPGuard bans the IP after 3 failed login attempt and in the image above are reported these 3 failed login attempts.

Please note PID 13208 is RDPGuard and PID 480 is RPC Service (svchost).

Note also that no connections to the RDP Port is present.



@yagmoth555, I understand what you told me about layers, but now I configured the firewall to log also permitted packed, as you can see in the log extraction.
Even if firewall filters packets after RDPGuard, it has a chance to block/unblock the packet because if I don't exclude "OpenVPN Tap-WindowsX" network in the firewall properties, i cannot access with RDP.
This is the log portion for a successfully RDP connection:
(PID 9560 is Terminal Service)


It seems they have done a connection to a public IP address to a 10.8.0 no, they did not. That should never be the assumption. Where is the network diagram and firewall configuration?

@GregAskew I tried to add extra information to the question.

You installed a VPN product on a resource that you need to protect.

This would be a variation of the infamous "Crazy VPN" solution. Right up there with "VPN the hard way" and "Oprah VPN".

Yes, I have only one server and I have no control on the network topology of the provider, so I tried to prevent some attacks with what I have.


Now, I still have RDP intrusion attempts, as seen in RDPGuard
software. I have done this checks:

Windows Firewall is a stateless firewall which work in layer 3, while most other product like wireshark and possibly RDPGuard work in layer 2. That make such tool will display incoming packets that wasnt filtered yet by the Windows Firewall.
Outbound it's the reverse, the security software would not see the packet as it was filtered by the firewall before.
You can see that question; What's the Wireshark packet receiving and processing procedure on a Windows machine? or that one; https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/38077/does-wireshark-see-packages-blocked-by-firewall-or-f-secure/ for more explanation.

This is my first question on this site, so in addition to downvote
please tell me where I can improve the question.

I didn't downvoted, but the question is well wrote honnestly, but the only point that I didn't like is more the fact the server is directly on the Internet. IMO it's a security's risk from the start. A general's advice if you want to make a more secure setup it would be to use a router or appliance that you could do like country blocking from it and could deploy the VPN from it. Now the DPI inside some routers are a lot advanced and can help to prevent some risks (like for CrypterLocker; as some router block TOR connection or block client to start unautorized proxy use, etc..). I never liked the idea to bring a server directly on the internet, unless it's a router appliance like a free sophos utm or such.

Thank you for the answer. The server is a dedicated server hosted by a provider. I cannot put a router before without considering a more expensive hosting solution. I'm still investigating but perhaps the problem was port 135 ( I updated the original question with my investigations).

@Marco like I told, the tool can see a packet coming in, but it's before the firewall analyse it, so technically speaking there can be no threat here. To test my answer enable the log file for the RDP service inside the Windows Firewall. After that you will see blocked RDP attempt or successful one to the service.  No log mean the packet wasnt seen in the end by the firewall. (%windir%\system32\logfiles\firewall\pfirewall.log) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/configure-logging?tabs=intune
